# Derivative in the direction of u+v is equal to the sum of the derivative in the direction of u and the derivative in the direction of v

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to prove that

> $D_{u+v}f(a)=D_{u}f(a)+D_{v}f(a)$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for any two
>   vectors $u,v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I try to use the definition and so forth but I could not prove it. I need to prove this only by using the definition, which is $$D_{v}f(a)=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}{t}$$.

Comment: Do you know that $D_u f(a) = \langle \nabla f(a), u \rangle$?

Comment: I am studying from a book called first steps in differential geometry and I am only allowed to use the definitions provided, gradient operator is not introduced. Maybe I should have added this to the question...

Comment: Start by plugging in each side of the equation into the definition.

Comment: I have done that, I could not continue. Seems like a simple proof but I must be missing something. I can't seem to find a way to obtain a nicer form for  $f(a+tv+tu)$ involving $f(a+tu)$ and $f(a+tv)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prove this if you  just assume that the given function is [Gâteaux differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative). You need  full [Fréchet differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative), *differentiability* for short, if you want to prove your claim. Consider the following example:
$$f(x):=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\>{\rm sgn}(x_2)\ ,$$
whereby ${\rm sgn}(0):=0$. We have
$$D_u f(0)=\lim_{t\to0}{f(t\, u)\over t}=\lim_{t\to0}{|t|\,|u|\>{\rm sgn}(t\,u_2)\over t}=|u|\,{\rm sgn}(u_2)\ .$$
The RHS here is defined for all $u\in{\mathbb R}^2$, but clearly not additive.

This example shows that differentiability is a stronger condition than what you are allowed to assume. If your $f$ is in fact Fréchet differentiable then it is easy to prove your claim: One has 
$$f(a+ tu)-f(a)=df(a).(t\,u)+o\bigl(|t\, u|\bigr)= t \bigl(df(a).u+o(1)\bigr)$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{t\to0}{f(a+ tu)-f(a)\over t}=df(a).u\ ,$$
which is clearly linear in $u$.

Comment: Great, I didn't know these definitions but by assuming them, the rest is understandable. The annoying thing is that how come using another equivalent definition involving gradients requires nothing but a simple computation yet this one seems like it assumes something more, how come is this possible? Am I misunderstanding something? Also, this example is from a book which does not assume that readers are accustomed to these definitions. Weird.